# WCF: Object Reference Not Set To Instance Of a an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, class

I have a CibilResponse Class that has properties that are of class type (TUEF class). I am trying to assign value to `CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version` but i am getting null reference error. Before you mark this question as duplicate let me mention that I have read some of the similar questions and their answers on SO and post which I have initialized tuef in the constructor as you can see in my code. Can you please point out if you can what is it that I am doing wrong?

**ICIBIL.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICIBIL
{

    [OperationContract]
    string InsertCibil(CibilResponse cibilResponse);


    [OperationContract]
    string GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiry testObj);


}

[DataContract]
public class CibilResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ResponseString { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Business { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MkrId { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class CibilEnquiry
{
    [DataMember]
    public TUEF Tuef { get; set; }   

    public CibilEnquiry()
    {
        this.Tuef = new TUEF();
    }

}


    [DataContract]
    public class TUEF
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SegmentTag { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string MemberReferenceNumber { get; set; }        

    }
```

**Appication :**

```
CibilWcfService.CIBIL obj = new CibilWcfService.CIBIL();
CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();
CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef.Version = "123";// null reference error here
string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
```

Comment: @MohitShrivastava As I have already mentioned I have read that post and upon which I also initialized tuef in constructor but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef could be null. please verify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the below. C# is case sensitive.

```
using CbilFileReader.CibilWcfService;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            CIBIL obj = new CIBIL();
            CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilEnquiry();
            TUEF objtuef = new TUEF();
            objtuef.Version = "123";
            CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef = objtuef;
            string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes am editing the response. I felt Tuef Class is part of CibilEnquiryEnq.

Comment: `The type or namespace Tuef could not be found..`

`CibilEnquiry does not exist in current context.`

Comment: I am not able to find `Tuef`
I am getting `type or namespace Tuef could not be found` at `Tuef objtuef=new Tuef();`

Comment: Can you share the Reference.cs file which gets added after adding the service reference.  can you try by adding a using CibilWcfService; statement in your application

Comment: Here you go. This should work

Comment: After adding `CibilWcfService.` as prefix ..Yes it worked! I wonder if there is a better way to assign values other than this. But Thanks it answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
CibilWcfService.CIBIL obj = new CibilWcfService.CIBIL();
CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry CibilEnquiryEnq = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry();
CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry.Tuef ObjTUEF = new CibilWcfService.CibilEnquiry.Tuef();
ObjTUEF.Version="123";
CibilEnquiryEnq.Tuef = ObjTUEF;
string res = obj.GenerateEnquiry(CibilEnquiryEnq);
```

Comment: I am getting : `Tuef is a property but is used like a type`